# jQuery Ajax and POST method in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two files `basic.php` and `pptimeline.php`. The purpose here is to select a value from a combobox in `basic.php`, process it in the `pptimeline.php` and print it back in `basic.php`. But I'm not having success in doing so. If anyone can help I appreciate.

EDIT: The `pptimeline.php` file acts as a json file `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. It has only querys which I then echo in the file but are not relevant here since everything works if I use default values instead of `$nprocess` in the query. The code that displays my data is inside the `sucess:` parameter in `basic.php`. If I remove what is around it everything works fine, but then it doen'st change based on what I choose.

Basic.php

```
<label for="Process"> NProcess : </label>
<select id="cproc">
  <?php
foreach ($products as $res3)
    {echo "<option value='".$res3["PROCESSO"]."'>".$res3["PROCESSO"]."</option>";}
    ?>
    </select>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $("#cproc").on("change", function(){
        var v1 = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "pptimeline.php", 
            type: "POST", 
            data: {'value' : v1}, 
            success: function(response){

            /**DISPLAY DATA IN INTERFACE**/
             var tg1 = {};
    $(function () { 
        // jQuery widget implementation
        // with some basic options
        tg1 = $("#placement").timeline({
                "min_zoom":1, 
                "max_zoom":55, 
                "image_lane_height":100,
                "icon_folder":"timeglider/icons/",
                "data_source":"pptimeline.php",
                "constrain_to_data": false
        });
        tg_actor = tg1.data("timeline");
        // You'll use tg_actor as the key to access 
        // public API methods like "goTo", etc.         
    }); // end document-ready
                      /****/

   }, error: function(x,y,z){
                alert("error"); } }); }); 
</script>
```

pptimeline.php

```
if (isset ($_POST['value'])) {
    $nprocesso = $_POST['value'];

$query1 = "SELECT TO_CHAR(DATACRIACAO,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATACRIACAO, NPROCESSO, 
BLOCOOPERATORIO, TIPOINTERNAMENTO, TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA, GLASGOW_HOSPITAL 
FROM PATIENT_TIMELINE_ADMISSAO WHERE NPROCESSO =".$nprocesso."";
}
```

Comment: Is that the complete pptimeline.php file? I don't see where you are executing the query or returning any results. Also, you should be binding the value instead of using a post parameter directly.

Comment: The `pptimeline.php` file acts as a json file `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. It has only querys which I then echo in the file but are not relevant here since everything works if I use default values instead of `$nprocess` in the query. The code that displays my data is inside the `sucess:` parameter in `basic.php`. If I remove what is around it everything works fine, but then it doen'st change based on what I choose.

Comment: You have `"data_source":"pptimeline.php",` in your `tg1 = $("#placement").timeline({`. The `value` you post in your `$.ajax()` is not retained. You could either save it as a `$_SESSION` var, or append it to the `data_source` url.

Comment: The code inside the `sucess:` is just to display the data processed in `pptimeline.php` in the screen. I don't see what is has to do with passing the variable I selected in the combo box to the `pptimeline.php` file with POST method

Comment: When you do your `$.ajax()` call, it posts `data: {'value' : v1}, ` to `url: "pptimeline.php",`. But when you get to `tg1 = $("#placement").timeline({...` and when it calls `"data_source":"pptimeline.php",`, there is no posted `value`, so `if (isset ($_POST['value'])) {` will be false, which would cause your issue. Posted data is not persistent, so you either need to make it persistent or send it with your second call to the page/script.

Comment: Yes, I have realized that myself, but I don't know how I am supposed to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.ajax()` call is unnecessary. Remove it, and just add your selected value to the `.timeline()` `data_source`-

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $("#cproc").on("change", function(){
        var v1 = $(this).val();
        var tg1 = {};
        $(function () { 
            // jQuery widget implementation
            // with some basic options
            tg1 = $("#placement").timeline({
                "min_zoom":1, 
                "max_zoom":55, 
                "image_lane_height":100,
                "icon_folder":"timeglider/icons/",
                "data_source":"pptimeline.php?value="+v1, //add select value to url
                "constrain_to_data": false
            });
            tg_actor = tg1.data("timeline");
            // You'll use tg_actor as the key to access 
            // public API methods like "goTo", etc.         
        }); // end document-ready
    }); 
</script>
```

Then change your php code from `$_POST` to `$_GET`

```
if (isset ($_GET['value'])) {
    $nprocesso = $_GET['value']; //make sure to sanitize value to prevent SQL injection

    $query1 = "SELECT ... NPROCESSO =".$nprocesso."";
}
```